# System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Tags: c#

I used `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` on my `Textbox`, but whenever I *enter* the `Textbox` and *leave* **without altering the value** it *adds two more zeros*, how can I sort this out?

```
private void textBox1_Leave_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  double txt = double.Parse(textBox1.Text,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
           
  textBox1.Text = txt.ToString("N2");

  return;
}
```

Comment: an if statement to check if textBox1.Text == text then just return if not the add the tostring

Comment: `txt.ToString("N2");` specifically telling the program to print the number with two decimals (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)).. am i missing something?

Comment: ... there is `NumericUpDown`  (in winforms)

Comment: Could you please update the question with a better title? "System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" doesn't describe your problem and makes it harder for people to find it in the future.

Comment: I assume that the root cause of your problem is that you use InvariantCulture for parsing, but CurrentCulture for formatting. Dmitry's answer shows you how to use InvariantCulture for ToString as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general case, you can *keep a collection* of `Coltrol`s which were *manually* edited and on control leaving check if the control is in the collection. Assuming that you work with *WinForms*:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

private readonly HashSet<Control> m_EditedControls = new HashSet<Control>();

// On each textBox1 change we should decide if we are going
// to update control's Text on leave or not
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // If TextBox1 was edited while having keyboard focus,
  // i.e. user got focus and edit the textbox manually
  // put textbox as edited   
  if (sender is TextBox box && box.Focused) 
    m_EditedControls.Add(box);
}
```

Then on leaving `textBox1` you can check if `textBox1` has been edited manually:

```
// On leaving textBox1 we and an additional check 
// if textBox1 has been edited manually
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (sender is TextBox box &&
      m_EditedControls.Contains(box) &&
      double.TryParse(box.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var value)) {
    box.Text = value.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    m_EditedControls.Remove(box);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, when I put the suggested code it gives  me an error in visual studio, it underlines TryParse in red., and out var value

Comment: @Hariche Arquissandas: Have you added `using System.Globalization;`?

Comment: Yes I did add using System.Globalization;, the error is on Trypass and var value,  both are underlined in red in visual studio